# jQuery-animate() can't stop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button used to scroll back to the top of the page when clicked.
I want to have an animation effect.

```
$("#back-to-top").click(function() {
        $(document.body).animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);
        return false;
    });
```

When I click on the button, it did scroll back to top. However, I can't scroll down and it seemed when I scroll down the function is called.
When I use

```
            $(document).scrollTop(0);
```

it works well.
What's the problem?
Here's my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/penguin_penpen/mz4gb486/5/)
I'm new to Fiddle, it just didn't work!

Comment: It seems this script working good, see [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmjkgmw5/) , probably there is something else wrong.

Comment: @jiff, look in other browser :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
$("#back-to-top").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("body, html").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);
});
```

**Update**
According to your fiddle, you have to put this function outside of `$(window).scroll( function() {});`

Comment: Works for me [see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6pbcfgq9/) Note : check your console, he has a syntax error in his fiddle.

Comment: It works perfect for me! Could you please explain why I can't put these code in the scroll function? I thought only when I click the button did the animate() function called?

Comment: If you put your jQuery click function in the scroll function, you bind a new click event on your button every pixel scrolled, causing your bug. This is why you need to bind your click event in the document ready. This way you bind your event only one time.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is actually browser based, I tested this in Firefox which it didn't work. I then tested it in Chrome and it worked fine. Try using `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0},500);` instead.